# cant use liquid simulation (mesh) - it is always solid

Tags: fluid-simulation

I try to follow multiple tutorials and it doesn't work for me. I've created domain, and flow,  on every tutorial - whey they check (on domain) that it is a mesh - the domain solid shape disappears and starts to be generated 'particle'. (like in this example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6B0QM4Cft5c)  not in my case. it is still solid and nothing works. please help. did record it so it should make more sense than my vogue explanation ;)

this is how it looks for me: https://youtu.be/-udvlz-nqBo

please help ;)

Comment: I cannot see in your video that you have baked the simulation. Have you baked it?

Comment: I can only say what I always say in these cases: did you follow those "multiple tutorials" thoroughly? Did you pay close attention to what they did? Because as @Blunder said, it doesn't seem like you have baked the simulation. And I'm sure that's what is done in almost all of the tutorials. Even when you leave the _Cache Type_ at _Replay_ where you create a cache "on the fly" and there is no _Bake_ button, you still need a simulated cache. If you don't run the simulation to created a cache or switch any settings so that the cache is erased, there will be no liquid to be seen.

Comment: hello, please remove all the useless objects and share your object: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: ...by the way, the tutorial you linked for example explains from minute 5:00 on that it's quite unstable to leave the cache at _Replay_ and better use a file cache type like _Modular_ or _All_.

Comment: In your video, you are at frame 26 as you play with the settings.   You need to set the timeline to frame 1, and then "run" the timeline.  This will *bake* (calculate) the simulation frames and start to render properly.

Comment: @james_t Yep, that's what I meant... I'm sure there was no cache created up to that point. Or lost again.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann -- I pity the new user that I once was.  Such a steep learning curve that I'm still climbing 2 years later!

Comment: @james_t Well, but the concept of baking any kinds of simulation or else they could be messed up in rendering etc. I learned very quickly. Of course the more specific problems and many options and settings of the different simulations are consuming more time and there's often room for improvement. The best thing is when doing tutorials, follow closely. Make sure you understand and recreate everything correct. And even better, don't follow along with it, just watch it completely the first time before trying to recreate it.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann - other tutorial problems: 1) lack of clarity from some sources, 2) old version of blender.